# How to use MySQL from WAMP with Zend Server CE?

Tags: mysql, zend-server-ce

I installed WAMP, then I installed Zend Server CE and both servers are working (both are on port 80 but I'm only running one server at a time).
But MySQL is not working with Zend Server.
I don't want to install another mysql server because I want to use the databases created with WAMP.
And I want to be able to test the same app in both servers.

**Do you know how to configure Zend Server for using MySQL from WAMP?**

Thanks !

EDIT: just to clarify:
I can run Zend Server OK, and run my PHP code, but I can't connect to mysql neither with PHP nor with MySQL Workbench if I'm using Zend Server (when I change to WAMP everything works fine again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem so I'm putting the solution here:
When you init wamp server it starts mysql service too automatically
When you close it, it closes mysql too
So if you run Zend Server you need to start mysql manually.

Or you could do this:

**1)** Open Wamp
**2)** Don't close Wamp, just shutdown the Apache service from Wamp menu (it will let mysql service running)
**3)** Start Zend Server